# Condition to minimize sum

Tags: summation, algorithms

Given three arrays $a,b,c $ we define summation as sum of all values of

$$S = \sum_{i=1}^n (a_{i}b_{i} + b_{i}c_{i} + c_{i}a_{i})$$

What condition or rearrangement of array should be done to get minimum value of summation

My first thought was to either arrange 2 of 3 arrays in ascending and third in descending or first 2 arrays in descending and last array in ascending but this doesn't seem to work

This was based on the approach that if there are two arrays then minimum sum will be obtained when one is ascending and other is descending array

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  A natural starting point might be to consider the same problem for two arrays.

Comment: In keeping with the two array approach, I would look at maximizing variance index by index.  Take the set of three elements with maximal variance, then repeat. (just a thought, not sure it works).